# How to open a map URL in Google Maps directly on click of a button in Flutter for mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-maps, dart

I am developing a flutter app for iOS that has a button , which is supposed to take the user to a google map address onclick of it. I have tried the following code :

```
void _launchMapsUrl(map_url) async {
  final url = map_url;
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
   throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

But, this opens the browser with an "OPEN" button, onclick of which its goes to the google maps. I would like to have a solution, which can directly take me to Google maps.

Comment: What is your map_url?

Comment: @armstrong For example "https://maps.app.goo.gl/" and slash followed by customized address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a great package that helps you to choose existing navigation apps [map launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/map_launcher)

easy to implement

```
final availableMaps = await MapLauncher.installedMaps;
```

here second option: you don't have to write the address I added to show you. here is package [intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent)

```
final AndroidIntent intent = new AndroidIntent(
            action: 'action_view',
            data: Uri.encodeFull(
                "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=" +
                    address1 +
                    "&destination=" +
                    address2 +
                    "&travelmode=driving&dir_action=navigate"),
            package: 'com.google.android.apps.maps');
        intent.launch();
```

check first does phone has google maps

isInstalled =
await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled("com.google.android.apps.maps");

if it doesn't

```
 var urlAppleMaps = "http://maps.apple.com";
        await launch(urlAppleMaps);
```

Comment: Thank you. But is it mandatory to provide coordinates. Is there a way where i can pass map URL.

Comment: This supports only for Android. It crashes for iOS.

Comment: ok bro I made the last edit added check install then open with ios map.